# How to have Geany create backup files with OpenVMS Files-11 style file names with version numbers?

Tags: versioning, geany, openvms

Will [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany) create backup files using the OpenVMS Files-11 version naming? For example, `x.txt.3` for the third version of `x.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Geany core is not supporting such a feature. But there is a plugin called [SaveActions](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#save-actions) available providing a similar feature. However, usually I ask people in such situations to use some VCS as git or mercurial which in most cases makes more sense than to keep many files.